# Sidebar footer of Material Dashboard 2 (free version) by Creative Tim

Tags: css

In the [demo](https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-dashboard/examples/dashboard.html) of Creative Tim's [Material Dashboard 2 (free version)](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard), the sidebar footer occupies quite a lot of space (up to 360px tall), and some menu items cannot be shown if the browser window is not tall enough.

Is there any chance that I can remove the footer?

I can see from the CSS class of the navigation items, the affecting property is:

```
.navbar-vertical.navbar-expand-xs .navbar-collapse {
    height: calc(100vh - 360px);
}
```

However, removing the sidebar footer (the element with `.sidenav-footer` class) doesn't help and 360px tall is still occupying the space. How to make the sidebar footer goes away and not occupy spaces? Any official CSS class to do so?

In the [official documentation](https://www.creative-tim.com/learning-lab/bootstrap/navbar/material-dashboard), it doesn't really mention anything about the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the navbar is determined by the classes that you mentioned, `.navbar-vertical.navbar-expand-xs .navbar-collapse`, which are assigned to the `div` containing the `ul` for the navbar. The footer is only 80px tall, and there is nothing but empty space between the footer and the navbar. It has nothing to do with the size of the footer. Rather, the `div` containing the menu items is too small.

If you want that `div` to be larger, you can change it's height value. Right now it's calculated as 100 percent the height of the viewer, minus `360px`. Change it to something lower than `360px`. Try this:

```
.navbar-vertical.navbar-expand-xs .navbar-collapse {
    height: calc(100vh - 200px);
}
```

Note that if you use a number that's too low, lower than `190px` (the height of the navbar header + the height of the footer + the margin of the navbar), the navbar items may go beyond the area of the navbar. You can find these height values in the web inspector.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to adjust the values as well, but such override does not look like an official way to solve the problem. Why does Material Dashboard set the calculated height like this?